# Selenium WebDriver, Can't properly select/assert a radio button on amazon? Any tips?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[link to the page with buttons](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-preferences/select-language/ref=topnav_lang?ie=UTF8&preferencesReturnUrl=%2Fb%2Fref%3Ds9_acss_bw_cg_147ECPv2_2b1_cta_w%3Fnode%3D12691224011%26pf_rd_m%3DATVPDKIKX0DER%26pf_rd_s%3Dunified-hybrid-3%26pf_rd_r%3DP9VPVM94B4HVV8WQZ9YS%26pf_rd_t%3D101%26pf_rd_p%3D45797eec-3609-4e49-908f-fe170faf8aaf%26pf_rd_i%3D13896617011)

One of my attempts:

```
@Test
public void checkRadioBtn()
{ 
    WebElement langEng = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='customer-preferences']/div/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/label/i"));

    if(!langEng.isSelected())
    {
        langEng.click();
    }

    assertTrue("English is selected", langEng.isSelected());     

}
```

assertTrue should throw and error if the condition is false. The option is selected, it throws an AssertionError. What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xpath that you are using is not getting the selected value from the radio button. That is why you are getting an assertion error. The value from the radio button is .//*[@id='customer-preferences']/div/div/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/label/input

so you would need one selector for the actual selection of the radio button
and one selector for getting the value from the radio button